# naming parameters for ORMLITE

Tags: ormlite, field-names

I have looked through the ORMLITE Documentation for naming. 
Let's say I have an object called Contract. When I call the API for Contract, it contains two parameters: name & type. When I create a class for Contract, do I have to match the two parameters with that from the API call, so that it regconise those parameters? 
i.e.

```
public class Contract {
    @Key
    @DatabaeField(columnName = BaseColumns._ID, id = true)
    public int id;
    @Key
    @DatabaseField
    public String name;
    @Key
    @DatabaseField
    public String type;

    public Contract() {}
}
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.  Can you add more details?  Are you trying to do a query?

Comment: could the String type be named "category" instead? I retrieve data using API call, does it mean that I have to match my class's field name with the api's ones?